# c++: класс-декоратор

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, методы, декоратор

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать следующее:

создать свой класс-декоратор, который оборачивает все функции дочернего класса некоторым функционалом

например класс

```
std::vector<int>
```

оборачивается через наследование в декоратор

```
CDecorator<std::vector<int>> obj;
```

после чего вызов

```
obj.push_back(11);
```

будет выполнять некоторый универсальный метод класса CDecorator

```
template <class T>
CDecorator::method()
{
     myFunc();

     T::push_back(11);
}
```

Интересует именно универсальный метод для любого класса

Comment: Каждый метод? Нет, для этого нужна рефлексия и кодогенерация, а их нет.

Comment: Самое близкое, что приходит в голову, это предоставлять доступ к методам вектора через `operator->`, и вызывать в нем нужный код.

Comment: Пример декоратора, на основе `operator->` : https://ideone.com/fQC5wT

Comment: @ixSci, звучит как приговор) А жаль.